# How to split lists at spaces Python

Tags: python, list, split

Python beginner here.
I have a function that is supposed to open two files, split them at spaces, and store them in lists, for access in another function. 
My first function goes something like:

```
listinput1 = input("Enter the name of the first file that you want to open: ")
listinput2 = input("Enter the name of the first file that you want to open: ")
list1 = open(listinput1)
list1 = list(list1)
list2 = open(listinput2)
list2 = list(list2)
metrics = plag(list1, list2)
print(metrics)
```

But when I execute the second function, I see that the list isn't split at the spaces like I intended it to be. I have tried the split function, and I have also attempted to use a for loop to iterate over each increment of the list as well.

Comment: `list1 = list1.read().split()`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: @Boosted, split on spaces or all whitespace?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham spaces only.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thank you, that helps a lot!

Comment: @BoostedNero, then pass `" "` explicitly to split

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

- When you `open()` a file, you need to `close()` it as well. You’re not doing this (and in general, doing it separately is a bad idea because the close might be missed if the program hits an exception first).

  The preferred Python idiom here is `with open(path) as f`:

  ```
  with open(listinput1) as f:
     # do stuff with f
  ```
- When you call `open(listinput1)`, you get a file object. Calling `list()` on this will get a list of lines from the file, for example:

  ```
  # colours.txt
  amber
  blue
  crimson | dark green
  ```

  ```
  with open('colours.txt') as f:
      print(list(f))  # ['amber', 'blue', 'crimson | dark green']
  ```

  To get a string containing text from the file, call the `read()` method on the object, then use the `split()` method on that string.

  ```
  with open('colours.txt') as f:
      text = f.read()         #  'amber\nblue\ncrimson | dark green'
      print(text.split(' '))  # ['amber\nblue\ncrimson', '|', 'dark', 'green']
  ```
- You’re asking for the first file twice. Should the second string be “Enter the name of the *second* file that you want to open”?

Here’s an updated version of your code with those changes:

```
path1 = input("Enter the name of the first file that you want to open: ")
path2 = input("Enter the name of the second file that you want to open: ")

with open(path1) as f1:
    list1 = f1.read().split(' ')

with open(path2) as f2:
    list2 = f2.read().split(' ')
```